# Nvidia Drivers, Ubuntu 12.10, GeForce GT 540m

Tags: drivers, 12.10, nvidia, graphics

How do I install Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 12.10? I have a GeForce GT 540m and have been trying to do this for the past 2 months with no luck. I tried the official repository, then I added the x swat ppa. I've installed Linux-headers-generic and Linux-source, and virtually every solution google has to offer. Throughout the course of this I must have done at least 25 fresh installs of Ubuntu; does anybody else(with a GT 540m) have this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work). You need bumblebee. Read thoroughly in the link. I have 540m too

Comment: Hi Stacks, if you got it working you might consider answering your own question.

Comment: And another perfect use case for TL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I found the answer, this is me posting it. The fix here is bumblebee. Nvidia cards that use Optimus, such as the 540m, need to be able to utilize Optimus in order to function properly. Well, not really; but without Optimus the computer can't differentiate between the two cards. [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) allows support for Optimus on Linux systems. Install it, and the problem will cease to exist.